# How Test laravel successive jobs?

Tags: laravel, testing, queue, jobs

I'm using **Laravel 5.6** and should create feature test for some functionality. How I can test dispatching of 2 jobs, in case of the second job executed from first, under certain conditions.

it looks like this:

```
class FirstJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public function handle()
    {
        dispatch(new SecondJob());
    }
}
```

sequential asserting can't see the second **Job.**

`Queue::assertPushed(FirstJob::class);` // asserted

`Queue::assertPushed(SecondJob::class);` // not asserted

Comment: For everyone reading this at any time (2021+), this is not exactly a good test, as you are instantiating a job, dispatching it and then "handling" it, when you should dispatch it and done, check that your testing environment is handling any job synchronously, so everything runs out of the box. Also, if you are faking the `Queue`, then this makes no sense... it should be dispatched when you try a feature test...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just dispatch the `firstJob` and then call the `handle()` method

Example:

```
$new_job = new FirstJob();
$new_job->dispatch();

Queue::assertPushed(FirstJob::class, function(){
    // check some job property against the expected
});

$new_job->handle();

Queue::assertPushed(SecondJob::class, function(){
    // check some job property against the expected
});
```